# Video Jerkiness calculation

Tags: video, mp4

For calculating Jerkiness in video following three parameters are required:

1.Motion intensity.

How i can calculate the motion intensity off video frame.Is it equal to sum of pixel differences between one frame and the succeeding frame.Is it the right approach.

2.Frame repetition probability
How can i determine the frame repetiition probability.Completely clueless on how to determine this parameter.

3.Frame display time:

For 60Hz video file video is displayed every 1/60=16ms.So if 16ms also is also the video display time.Or how can i correctly determine frame display time

Regards
Mayank

Comment: "Video jerkiness" is the failure to display the correct frame at the given time. Usually due to network issues or a broken bitstream. You three points, are those a statement from you or are they the input you are given by somebody?

Comment: Hi,These three points are from ITU J.341 standard.